# need support making a python increment loop using pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, increment

This is my 2nd day using python so go easy,

Heres my code

```
pyautogui.press('down')
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.click((848, 480))
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.click((350, 280))
time.sleep(0.5)
```

I want to be able to loop this but each time it loops it adds another pyautogui.press('down') at the top,
right now its just manually repeated in the code getting longer and longer and its terrible.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?  This can help us help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add commands to your script, but you could loop the `pyautogui.press()` command:

```
#We declare the repeat variable.
repeat=1
#Loop...
while True:
 #Repeat the command as much times as the repeat variable states.
 for _ in range(repeat):
  pyautogui.press('down')
 #Rest of the code...
 time.sleep(0.5)
 pyautogui.click((848, 480))
 time.sleep(0.5)
 pyautogui.click((350, 280))
 time.sleep(0.5)
 #We increment the amount of times the pyautogui.press() command will be called.
 repeat+=1
```